# Angular splits ng-models on '_' and creates array. Why? And how do I stop it?

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I have a HTML form with a bunch of inputs named `geometrie_1_bezeichnung`, `geometrie_1_stack`, `geometrie_2_bezeichnung`, `geometrie_2_stack` and so forth.

ng-model of these fields is created dynamically like `product.geometrie_2_bezeichnung`.

`$scope.submitSave = function(product){ console.debug(product) }`

Angular splits these values and creates arrays like `geometrie[][bezeichnung]` and adds these to my `product`object.

My CMS in the background doesn't like this. I want/need *only* the raw values. Is there any way to stop Angular from doing this? (This might be Angular 1.4 behaviour, not sure though)

Thanks,
thomas

Comment: Cannot see the issue you mentioned when using angular 1.4.7 on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/3rLwarn1/). Can you update it to reproduce the issue with your version of angular and the code?

Comment: Playing in the fiddle I can't see the issue either. Must have been something else and I managed to steer the ship around the issue. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to see your Code.

But to be sure... `geometrie_1_bezeichnung` is made to `geometrie[][bezeichnung]`?
Did you try to remove the underscores from the input names?

Comment: I need the underscores because it's a CMS naming convention. I works now, might even have been JQuery who did that. Thanks!